# Read XML Data and Update Variation Qty

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, woocommerce

As the title says I want to update the woocommerce product variation qty from the XML file, using the SKU as the common denominator.

Below is the code I have so far:

```
<?php
$xmldata = simplexml_load_file("URL_REMOVED") or die("Failed to load");

$dproduct_id = null;
$dsku = null;
$dqty = null;

foreach($xmldata->children() as $prod) {         
 $dsku = $prod->sku;       
 $dqty = $prod->qty; 

$idfromsku = wc_get_product_id_by_sku( $dsku );

echo $idfromsku;

}
```

Here's a sample from the XML data:

```
<products>
<product>
<sku>D0001B</sku>
<qty>100</qty>
</product>
</products>
```

My logic was "for each product, set $dsku to the value of sku, and $dqty to the value of qty", which it does, but i'm struggling with getting the product ID from the sku.

PHP isn't my strongest language so any help here would be appreciated.

Cheers D

Answer (score 1):

A common problem is that although your data looks as though it is a string.  When you `echo` some things - this will automatically cast the output to a string and may call a `__toString()` method in a class, so it just looks OK.  In the example you have

```
$dsku = $prod->sku;
```

if you dump the value (`var_dump()`) you should find that it is an instance of a SimpleXMLElement.  So if you want to pass this value to a function like `wc_get_product_id_by_sku()` you would need to force it to be a string...

```
$idfromsku = wc_get_product_id_by_sku( (string)$dsku );
```